# List of items and their scores - need to sort and find their position after sorting

Tags: java, sorting, position, element

I have a list of items like

### item - score

### shirts  - 1245

### watches - 25

### belts - 320

### shoes - 540

### soaps - 110

Now I want to sort this items by their score

---

### Sort Position - Score - Item

### 0 - 52 - watches

### 1 - 110 - sopas

### 2 - 320 - belts

### 3 - 540 - shoes

### 4 - 1245 - shirts

Now I need if I give item then I want to know its position

for example: if I say 'shirts' then it should return 4.

Is there a utility like that available? No of items will be 1000 and like this I have 10 different lists.

Please help me with this.

Comment: What tools, programming language do you have available? What environment, operating system, etc? It would be fairly easy to accomplish that task, but you will need to choose a programming language you want to work with.

Comment: I'm using java.

Comment: Have you got any java code you are already working with? If so, we'll need you to show an attempt. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43013162/edit) and include plain text code into your question. Otherwise, the site is not a tutoring or code writing service, although some users may be willing to help. Also, take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In what format is the list? Is that a text file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collection,comparator.I will show you sample code may be this will help you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
TreeMap items=new TreeMap(new Sorting());

items.put(new ListItems("shirts",1245),1245);
items.put(new ListItems("watches",25),25);

items.put(new ListItems("belts",320),320);

items.put(new ListItems("shoes",540),240);

items.put(new ListItems("soaps",110),110);


ArrayList<ListItems>l=new ArrayList(items.keySet());

for(ListItems list:l)
{

if(list.getItem().equalsIgnoreCase("watches"))
    System.out.println("index is : "+l.indexOf(list));
}
}
}

class ListItems
{
public String getItem() {
    return item;
}
public int getScore() {
    return score;
}
public void setScore(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}
public ListItems(String item,int score) {
    super();
    this.score = score;
    this.item = item;
}
private int score;
private String item;
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ListItems [score=" + score + ", item=" + item + "]";
}

}
class Sorting implements Comparator<ListItems>
{
@Override
public int compare(ListItems o1, ListItems o2) {
    if(o1.getScore()<o2.getScore())
        return -1;
    if(o1.getScore()>o2.getScore())
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
    }

}
```